Paraphrase or Quote Safety Guidelines in a Paper
I am currently writing a research paper that involves whether various sources involved in giving safety advice accurately list guidelines set out by governments/large organizations. I have created a table that includes all of the missed guidelines set out by the governing body from all of the sources that I have reviewed. Since these guidelines are quite simple (e.g. have someone else drive if you are feeling ill) and I explicitly list the source of these guidelines in the header row of the table (e.g. Header title: Missed guidelines from x), should I paraphrase the guidelines or list them as is?

I’ve removed the trailing question whether you need to quote something you copy verbatim, since it seemed like a technicality that detracts from the otherwise well focused question. Yes, if you copy something verbatim that is a quote and you must indicate this via formatting, commonly quotation marks.

What would the motivation be for paraphrasing them? It feels like there is probably some sort of misconception about plagiarism behind this question.

I assume you don't want to put quotation marks around every table entry, and I agree with that --- it would look ugly. But I still think you can use quotations rather than paraphrases provided you make it absolutely clear that these are quotations from the sources ion the headers. In my opnion, it would be sufficient to state that in the table's caption and also in the main text where the table is first mentioned.

What benefit to the reader will come from you paraphrasing the guidelines? Based on your description, I’d say the answer is “none”. Therefore in this situation, quoting seems like the best solution.
Paraphrasing makes sense in certain situations, for example when you are writing text in narrative form and feel like the flow of the text may be interrupted by the insertion of a quote, or if you genuinely believe your way of saying something is better than the way it was said in the reference you are citing, while retaining the original meaning. I can’t say for sure, but it does not sound like these considerations apply to the current case.

This is for your judgement since you see the text, but it would depend on whether you are able to paraphrase them completely accurately without quoting. That might be difficult for a variety of reasons, including the relative length of the advice in the various papers.
If you paraphrase to shorten them, then you might give the wrong impression.
An alternate solution is to include a paraphrase in the table for the longer ones, with the full text in foot/end notes as needed. Accuracy is essential.
